# Masonite - craft new command throws module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen' error

Tags: python, frameworks, masonite

I'm trying to use the Masonite framework and I just installed the `masonite-cli` package and whenever I run `craft new`, an `Attribute Error -  module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'` is thrown. My base Python version is 2.7 but I have 3.6 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this error is a little ambiguous, this is may seem like it is being thrown because of an incorrect Python version but the base craft commands are designed to be run on Python 2 and Python 3.

With that being said, this error is likely because of an SSL certificate error since Python 3.6 doesn't come with certificates. You can read more about fixing this error here: [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

but the solution to this is to just run: `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command`